# Group By COLOR in own group

Tags: vba

With RESPECT
How can Group by color?
I have a column with a lots of colored number group.
I wanna separate them within a macro in their own group by color.
PLEASE HELP.
REGARDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this manually *(from Ribbon commands)*, but if you need VBA, then do the manual process with the Recorder turned on and tweak the result.  Say we start with:

[image]

Running this:

```
Sub Macro1()
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields
        .Clear
        .Add(Range("A2:A23"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:A23")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]